# Disable flash in video.js

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, video.js

How can i prevent video.js to not use flash anymore ? I mean i only need it to run if the browser supports HTML5.

The fact that i am using Drupal it should not be a problem with configuring the javascript library , right ?

Answer (score 5):

Override the techOrder to include only HTML5. Add this to the data-setup attribute of the video tag:

```
<video … data-setup='{"techOrder": ["html5"]}'>
```