# Stop Video.JS falling back to Flash?

Tags: jquery, html, video, html5-video, video.js

I am using video.js to display a HTML5 video on my site. For some reason FireFox (v31, Mac) displays it as a fallback Flash video. I would rather this didnt happen and just showed an image instead as I am using CSS `width: 100%` to scale the `<video>` tag.

Does anyone know of a way to stop this from occurring?

My video.js is set up as such:

```
 <video class="video-js"
  controls autoplay preload="auto" width="auto" height="auto" 
  data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
 <source src="video/rad3.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
 </video>
```

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15522845) answer to the same question by misterben.

Comment: The reason it falls back to Flash is simply that Firefox on Mac cannot play MP4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable flash in video.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508563/disable-flash-in-video-js)